# процесс не может получить доступ к файлу так как он используется другим процесом

Tags: c#, сериализация

Есть класс для сериализации.И есть класс в котором она реализована.Но при открытии файла выбрасывается exception "процесс не может получить доступ к файлу так как он используется другим процесом"

```
   [Serializable]
    class Student
    {
        public string name;
        public string surname;
        public string patronymic;

        int bookNum;

        readonly string fullName;
        readonly int programmingAvg, AdminAvg, DesignAvg, allAvg;


        public DateTime dt;
        public int[][] marks = null;
        const int max = 12, min = 1;
        public enum Subject { Programming, Admin, Design };
        static string collageName = "Cambridge";
        static int studentCounter = 0;

        public Student(int[][] m, string name = "null", string surname = "null", string patronymic = "null", int year = 1999, int month = 1, int day = 1)
        {
            int[] @null = new int[1] { 1 };
            bookNum = ++studentCounter;
            dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.patronymic = patronymic;
            marks = new int[3][];
            RemoveDigits();
            fullName = this.name + " " + this.surname + " " + this.patronymic;
            if (m != null)
                setMarksProgramming(m[0]);
            else
                setMarksProgramming(@null);
            if (m != null)
                setMarksAdmin(m[1]);
            else
                setMarksAdmin(@null);
            if (m != null)
                setMarksDesign(m[2]);
            else
                setMarksDesign(@null);
            programmingAvg = marks[0].Sum() / marks[0].Length;
            AdminAvg = marks[1].Sum() / marks[1].Length;
            DesignAvg = marks[2].Sum() / marks[2].Length;
            allAvg = (programmingAvg + AdminAvg + DesignAvg) / 3;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            set { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) this.name = value; else this.name = "null"; }
            get { return name; }
        }
        public string Surame
        {
            set { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) this.surname = value; else this.surname = "null"; }
            get { return surname; }
        }
        public int Group { set; get; }
        public string Patronymic
        {
            set { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) this.patronymic = value; else this.patronymic = "null"; }
            get { return patronymic; }
        }
        private void RemoveDigits()
        {
            name = Regex.Replace(name, "[0-9]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            surname = Regex.Replace(surname, "[0-9]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            patronymic = Regex.Replace(patronymic, "[0-9]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
        static public int countOfStudent() { return studentCounter; }
        public void setMarksProgramming(int[] param)
        {
            marks[0] = param;
        }
        public void setMarksAdmin(int[] param)
        {
            marks[1] = param;
        }
        public void setMarksDesign(int[] param)
        {

            marks[2] = param;
        }
        public void SetMark(Subject subject, int numLesson, int mark)
        {
            if (subject == Subject.Programming)
                if (numLesson >= 0 && marks[0].Length > numLesson)
                    if (mark <= max && mark >= min)
                        marks[0][numLesson] = mark;
                    else if (subject == Subject.Admin)
                        if (numLesson >= 0 && marks[1].Length > numLesson)
                            if (mark <= max && mark >= min)
                                marks[1][numLesson] = mark;
                            else if (subject == Subject.Design)
                                if (numLesson >= 0 && marks[2].Length > numLesson)
                                    if (mark <= max && mark >= min)
                                        marks[2][numLesson] = mark;
        }
        public void clear()
        {
            Array.Clear(marks, 0, marks.Length);
        }
        public int AgeDate(DateTime DT)
        {
            return (DT - dt).Days / 365;
        }
        public int AgeNow
        {
            get { return (DateTime.Today - dt).Days / 365; }
        }
        public void print()
        {
            Console.Write($"\n{fullName}\n{AgeNow}\n{programmingAvg} {AdminAvg} {DesignAvg}  {allAvg}\n{bookNum} {collageName}\n");
            Console.Write("Programming: ");
            if (marks[0] != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < marks[0].Length; i++)
                    Console.Write(marks[0][i] + " ");
            else
                Console.Write("NULL");
            Console.Write("\nAdmin: ");
            if (marks[1] != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < marks[1].Length; i++)
                    Console.Write(marks[1][i] + " ");
            else
                Console.Write("NULL");
            Console.Write("\nDesign: ");
            if (marks[2] != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < marks[2].Length; i++)
                    Console.Write(marks[2][i] + " ");
            else
                Console.Write("NULL");
            Console.Write("\n\n ");
        }
        static public int Max(Student[] m)
        {
            return m.Max(st => st.allAvg);
        }
        static public int Min(Student[] m)
        {
            return m.Min(st => st.allAvg);
        }
        static public int Count(Student[] m, int param)
        {
            if (param == 0)
            {
                return m.Count(st => st.programmingAvg >= 7);
            }
            else if (param == 1)
            {
                return m.Count(st => st.AdminAvg >= 7);
            }
            else if (param == 2)
            {
                return m.Count(st => st.DesignAvg >= 7);
            }
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }
    class FileWorker
    {
        public static void SaveStudent(Student student, string filename)
        {
            using (StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(fs, student);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void LoadStudent(Student student, string filename)
        {
            using (StreamReader f = new StreamReader(filename))
            {

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    student = (Student)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[][] m3 = new int[3][] { new int[4] { 5, 4, 6, 6, }, new int[5] { 7, 5, 5, 4, 6 }, new int[4] { 12, 8, 12, 9 } };
        Student a = new Student(m3, "Misha", "Onyuk", "Petrovich", 2001, 1, 31);
        a.print();
        FileWorker.SaveStudent(a, "fILE");
        Student b = new Student(null);
        FileWorker.LoadStudent(b, "fILE");
        b.print();
    }
```

Comment: вам нужно закрывать filestream после того, как сделали все для вас необходимое. иначе просто файл будет заблокирован. есть такая вещь - fileshare(в конструкторе filestream).так вот если вы выставите на fileshare.ReadWrite, то можно использовать файл всем (в т.ч другим процессам). также, полезно помнить - если у вас многопоточное приложение и вас не устраивает по какой-либо причине fileshare.ReadWrite, то можно использовать lock(object).object - объект заглушка. так вот, когда какой-то поток будет работать с файлом, другой будет ждать пока тот закончит. главное, чтоб один объект-заглушка был.

Answer (score 2):

Вы дважды открываете один и тот же файл в методах `SaveStudent`/`LoadStudent`.

```
        //using (StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(filename))
        //{

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, student);
            }
        //}
```